# SSH key generation command

Tags: ssh-keys

Is it possible for an ssh user to generate symmetric key used to encrypt a session?  I have read about asymmetric key generation using ssh-keygen. Is something similar available?

Comment: Any user can generate ssh keys, if ssh-keygen is accessible. Being connected through ssh is not important.

Comment: ssh-keygen is used to generate asymmetric keys. I cant find any reference where it is used to generate symmetric key.

Answer (score 0):

No, ssh-keygen doesn't do that. It only generates authentication keys.

However, all SSH sessions are *already* encrypted. The SSH client *automatically* creates a symmetric key during the "kex" or "key exchange" stage using DH or ECDH, and uses it encrypt the whole session. (In fact, you cannot even turn it off.) So there's no reason to generate such keys manually.

Comment: So would that mean i cannot use any external methods to generate session keys ?

Comment: No, you cannot. Why would you need to?